# Radio Buttons / Checkboxes

Tags: php, html

I wasn't sure how to word the title, because just thinking about this concept kind of confuses me and I'm not sure why. I'm sure there is some simple solution to this.

Here is a picture of my codes (Attached below) output.
[image]

The user should be able to click 1 radiobox inside each box, but I can't seem to make it do that. The way it is right now, only 1 vacation button can be selected and only 1 absent button can be selected.

Here is my code:

```
if($loop < 4) {

    echo '<td>';

    echo '  NAME<BR><input type="radio" name="vacationTeammates[]" value="'.$value[0].'">Vacation<br>
            <input type="radio" name="absentTeammates[]" value="'.$value[0].'">Absent';

    echo '</td>';

    $loop++;
} else {
    $loop = 1;
    echo "</tr><tr align='center'>";

    echo '<td>';

    echo '  NAME<BR><input type="radio" name="vacationTeammates[]" value="'.$value[0].'">Vacation<br>
            <input type="radio" name="absentTeammates[]" value="'.$value[0].'">Absent';

    echo '</td>';

}
```

(The loop makes it so that the table row ends and starts a new one, so it is somewhat irrelevant but the radio buttons are what matters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @user3163495 & @FirstOne for a few tips I used in my answer here.

I made both of the radio buttons in each cell have the same name, and all the others have different names.

```
        if($loop < 4) {

            echo '<td>';

            echo '  <input type="radio" name="goneTeammates['.$uniqueLoop.']" value="'.$value[0].'|V">Vacation<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="goneTeammates['.$uniqueLoop.']" value="'.$value[0].'|A">Absent<br>NAME';

            echo '</td>';

            $loop++;
        } else {
            $loop = 1;
            echo "</tr><tr align='center'>";

            echo '<td>';

            echo '  <input type="radio" name="goneTeammates['.$uniqueLoop.']" value="'.$value[0].'|V">Vacation<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="goneTeammates['.$uniqueLoop.']" value="'.$value[0].'|A">Absent<br>NAME';

            echo '</td>';

        }
```

For the value, I used the teammates name (Actually their uniqueid) and an A for absent or V for vacation. The output would basically look like:

35|A

23|V

64|A

etc

On the processing side I `explode()`'d the input at that `|` sign, to basically get the uniqueID and the letter in seperate variables, and processed like normal from there.

Answer (score 1):

Each radio button pair must have the same "name" attribute value for browsers to know they're their own set.

Change your code to something like this, where "$SomeUniqueRowVar" is a variable that changes for each row:

```
echo 'NAME<BR>';
echo '<input type="radio" name="status'.$SomeUniqueRowVar.'" value="vacation">';
echo 'Vacation<br>';
echo '<input type="radio" name="status'.$SomeUniqueRowVar.'" value="absent">';
echo 'Absent';
```

Comment: That will work for the row, but if you look at the op's code, they reset `$loop` to `1`.

Comment: @FirstOne I can easily make another variable that counds during the loop, so that is no big deal

Comment: So, basically, each column would still be a single-selection

Comment: @user3163495 How would I then process this on the php side?

Comment: @user3163495 as FirstOne pointed out, this still doesn't work. This makes it so I can select both radios inside the boxes. Basically makes it so all radio buttons are selectable at the same time.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I overlooked the name values in my code. Try my code again

Comment: This is essentially what I did to get it to work, sort of.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a counter and assign each name to a specific array element, rather than just [].  Since you only want one of the radios to be selectable for each teammate, the inputs will have to be the same name but have different values.  Put the teammates name in an array (a variable separate from the radio inputs)  that uses the counter as it's index.  This way you know which response goes to which teammate.

```
if($loop < 4) {
    $name[$counter] = $value[0];
    echo '<td>';
    echo '  NAME<BR><input type="radio" name="teammates[$counter]" value=1>Vacation<br>
            <input type="radio" name="teammates[$counter]" value=0>Absent';
    echo '</td>';
    $counter++;
    $loop++;
} else {
    $name[$counter] = $value[0];
    $loop = 1;
    echo "</tr><tr align='center'>";
    echo '<td>';
    echo '  NAME<BR><input type="radio" name="teammates[$counter]" value=1>Vacation<br>
            <input type="radio" name="teammates[$counter]" value=0>Absent';
    echo '</td>';
    $counter++;
}
```

Now when you process the array, you will know if teammates[$counter] is 1 it means vacation and 0 it means absent.

You could also opt to use the name AS the index if you can be sure it is free of special characters/safely parse special chars out.

Comment: Read the answer from @user3163495. `as FirstOne pointed out, this still doesn't work. This makes it so I can select both radios inside the boxes. Basically makes it so all radio buttons are selectable at the same time.`

Comment: Edited to take into account that you want the name associated to each radio input and that only radio per name should be selectable.